# jquery - multiple select and then adjust based on each parents attribute

Tags: jquery-selectors

I want to do something to all my span elements that have a certain class value.

The something that I will want to do will be based upon an attribute value of the span elements parent.

Can anyone point in the right direction please.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span.MYCLASS').each(function() {
  switch($(this).parent().attr('THEATTRIBUTE'))
  {
    case 'something':
      // DO SOMETHING
      break;

    case 'somethingelse':
      // DO SOMETHING ELSE
      break;
  }
});
```

Change MYCLASS and THEATTRIBUTE to whatever you need them to be.  Then you can add in as many case statements as you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.spanClass").each(
    function(){
      $(this).width($(this).parent().width());
    }
)
```

if width is the attribute you want to change..

Answer (score 0):

Also, [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) can be very helpful when trying to determine how to select an element or a group of them.